# Is there ways to reduce the size of private app registry hive (RegLoadAppKey)?

Tags: windows, winapi, registry

I am trying to see if my app can use a **private registry hive** file to store data.

The private registry acts almost like a database, which consistently gets read, written, and deleted.

App runs fine and seems like it doesn't have any problem. But the **size**.

It seems like the hive file that is created using `RegLoadAppKey` does not reallocate its file size, even if the keys/values inside get deleted (or modified).

So when I stress the app with large number of transaction, the file only grows.

I have gone through MSDN briefly (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-files). It does not say much about App registry, but I can assume this method is not really suitable for what the app is trying to achieve.

Still, I am curious to know why the size only grows. And possibly if there is a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not using a database file? SQLite, XML. You can't control how the registry stores the values. It's likely that Windows will compact the registry from time to time.

Comment: Sounds like the registry may not be the solution. Why are you set on using it.

Comment: My app currently is using SQLite DB. The problem is, there are multiple processes that are accessing the DB at a fast rate. And somehow there is a inconsistency in data which are shared among processes. I thought registry will be a quite good solution, but I guess not.